# Is there a way to remove repository name from github page link?

Tags: github, github-pages

I created a page for a github repository following these instructions:[Getting Started with GitHub Pages](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/). Worked perfectly, the page is already hosted.

But I would like to change the page URL, This is the currently URL: http://myusername.github.io/repositoryName/

Is there any way to *remove the repository name*? (http://myusername.github.io/)

I've seen the [articles](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) to configure a custom domain, but I think that's not the case.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To remove the repository name, you'll need to make it a User Page (or an Organization page).  Create a repository named `myusername.github.io`, and commit your content to the `master` branch.  See [this help page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/) for more information.

Comment: Exactly what I looking for, it could not be complicated, I've seen several urls like this, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Ah, so the repository should be EXACTLY `name.github.io`, with the actual `.github.io` suffix at the end.  Thanks.

Comment: @ubomi thanks for pointing that out. I missed that too :-)

Comment: What about with custom domains ?

Comment: @behicsakar follow [these instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site)